# Remove \n from line but not after '.'

Tags: python

I want to remove new line (\n) from the string but not after '.'
for example
`first\n example\n is here.\n Second\n example is\n here.`

Expected output:

```
first example is here.
Second example is here.
```

Comment: "first\n example\n is here.\n Second\n example is\n here.".replace(".\n",".$").replace("\n","").replace("$","\n")

Answer (score 2):

You do this using a regex to substitute any newline chars not preceded by a `.`. regex explained [here](https://regex101.com/r/JYkb2F/1)

```py
import re

regex = r"([^.])\n"

test_str = "first\n example\n is here.\n Second\n example is\n here."

subst = "\\1"

result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str)
```

Answer (score 1):

try with
.replace(".\n",".$")

Answer (score 1):

You can use lookbehind for the dot:

```
import re
your_str = """first\n example\n is here.\n Second\n example is\n here."""
re_pattern = r'(?<=[^\.])\n'
print(re.sub(re_pattern, "", your_str))
```